# Construct a regular pentagon

Tags: geometry, polygons, geometric-construction

I want to construct a regular pentagon with side length $4$.

I have done the following:

We are given the segment $|AT|=4$ and we will create a point $B$ outside of $|AT|$ such that $|AB|$ is divided by $T$ in golden ratio.

We create the perpendicular line segment to $|AT|$ from $T$ with length $\overline{AT}$ and so we get the point $C$.

Then we create the midpoint $M$ of $|AT|$.

The circle around $M$ with radius $\overline{MC}$ intersects the extension of $|AT|$ from $T$ at the point $B$.

So we have that $\frac{\overline{AB}}{\overline{AT}}=\Phi$.

From that equation we get that $\overline{AB}=\overline{AT}\cdot \Phi=4\Phi$.

Then we create an isosceles triangle on the segment $|AT|$ with the two equal sides of length $\overline{AB}$ as follows:

We create a circle with center $A$ and radius $\overline{AB}$ and a circle with center $T$ and radius $\overline{AB}$. Let $P$ be the intersection point of the two circles, above of $|AB|$.
This is a triangle of type $1$.

On the sides $|AP|$ and $|TP|$ we create an isosceles triangle with two equal sides of length $4$.

Let's consider first the side $|AP|$.
We create a circle with center $A$ and radius $4$ and a circle with center $P$ and radius $4$. Let $K_1$ be the intersection point of the two circles, above of $|AP|$.
This is a triangle of type $2$.

Now we consider the side $|TP|$.
We create a circle with center $T$ and radius $4$ and a circle with center $P$ and radius $4$. Let $K_2$ be the intersection point of the two circles, above of $|TP|$.
This is a triangle of type $2$.

Now we have a regular pentagon.

Is everything correct?

To justify that these are indeed triangles of type $1$ and $2$ respectively do we calculate the angles using the cosine rule?

Comment: It suffices to use the [well-known result](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT725/SublimeTriangle/SublimeTri.html) that in an isosceles triangle with vertex angle of 36° base and side are in golden ratio.

Comment: Ok! But is the costruction that I described correct and complete? @Aretino

Comment: Boy it would sure help if the OP used *figures* instead of words.

Comment: It's absolutely correct.

Comment: You have here several constructions of a such regular pentagon, including one of Euclides: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construction_du_pentagone_r%C3%A9gulier_%C3%A0_la_r%C3%A8gle_et_au_compas

Comment: Ok!! Thank you!! :-)